# Road Symbology Issues

Tags: arcgis-10.1, cartography, arcgis-desktop, symbology

I have preparing road symbology using Arcmap 10.1 version. When I was prepared attribute based   symbology as a layer shown on symbols were overlapped. I have attached an example image to show the problem.[image]

Comment: Have you tried setting up [symbol levels](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/What_is_symbol_level_drawing/00s500000039000000/)?